# Which module is the most effective for excecuting bash shells in python3 with the least fuss

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

In python2 I would use the "commands" modules to execute bash commands. A typical usage is shown below below.

Given the script...

```
$cat sample.py 
import commands

print commands.getoutput("ls -l")
```

...running it gives:

```
$ python sample.py 
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 username  wheel  61 Jun 14 11:58 sample.py
```

How could I do something as simple and elegant as this in python3, which does not include the commands module???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `commands` module [has been deprecated](http://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html):

> Deprecated since version 2.6: The `commands` module has been removed in Python 3. Use the `subprocess` module instead.

As stated, use the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) instead, both in Python 2 *and* 3:

```
import subprocess

print(subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-l']))
```

Comment: Great, could you put in code snippet that does the equivalent of the above???....thanks!!